# SQL query error - Selecting from table with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to figure out how to make a query that fits my needs. It has to select a `modelid` from the creature table where the id = 553 and update the creature_template table column `displayid` with the id it has selected but only if entry = 100098.

I have written this SQL:

```
UPDATE `creature_template`
    SET `modelid1` = (SELECT `modelid`
                     FROM `creature`
                     WHERE `map` = 553)
    WHERE `entry` = 100098
```

However I get this error when I add it to my database:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery returns more than one value. That means, there are more than one rows in `creature` with `map` field equals 553. This query will update only one of that rows.

```
UPDATE `creature_template`
    SET `modelid1` = (SELECT `modelid`
                     FROM `creature`
                     WHERE `map` = 553
                     LIMIT 1
    )
    WHERE `entry` = 100098
```

But if you need to update all rows with `map`=553, you should use `IN` cause:

```
UPDATE `creature_template`
    SET `modelid1` IN (SELECT `modelid`
                     FROM `creature`
                     WHERE `map` = 553
    )
    WHERE `entry` = 100098
```

Comment: You are simply the best! I spend so long time trying to figure out what was wrong haha! Thanks alot!